# How to I "Submit the file attachment" to a job in ServiceM8?

Tags: curl

So I've followed the steps on http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/how-to-guides/attaching-files-to-a-job-diary/ for adding a PDF to a job diary in ServiceM8.
I'm a little lost as to why the final step is not working.  I've added the attachment to the job and had the UUID returned in the headers.  I've extracted that UUI and then, using curl and the following code;

```
$service_url="https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/9640887b-df46-4bfb-a47c-4afb20ed3d6b.file";
$curl = curl_init();
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user@domain.com:p@55w0rd");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I'm getting a "HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST Content-Length: 0 Connection: Close" as a response - any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually posting any file contents, i.e. your request is trying to attach an empty file.

Assuming your PDF was stored at `/tmp/cool_document.pdf`:

```
$service_url="https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/9640887b-df46-4bfb-a47c-4afb20ed3d6b.file";
$file_data = file_get_contents("/tmp/cool_document.pdf"); // read the file contents from disk

$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user@domain.com:p@55w0rd");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // This configures CURL to send a HTTP POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_data); // This puts your PDF file in the body of the HTTP request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Awesome - that was it :) I had been posting a reference to the file, following an answer to a support request through ServiceM8 customer support.